# Как изменить цвет фона каждого элемента selectItems в selectOneListbox?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

У меня есть элемент на странице

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="itemList">
<f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.selectedList}" />
```

в `selectedList` приходит список айтемов и в зависимости от того выполнился процесс или нет - рядом с айтем появляется фраза  `proccess failed` или `proccess success`.

Вся проблема состоит в том что в зависимости от фразы у `selectItems` должен окрашиваться фон в красный или зеленый цвета. Я не знаю как это сделать. Пыталась написать js функцию и вызвать ее всяческими путями, но ниразу эта функция не была вызвана. Либо она криво написана, либо как-то не так вызываю.

Функция выглядит вот так:

```
function highlightItems() {
 for (var i = 0; i &lt; 3; i++) {
  var curChild = "#itemList > div.ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer > ul > li:nth-child(" + i + ")";
           if($(curChild).text().indexOf("Success") != -1) {
              $(curChild).css({"background-color":"green !important"});
           } else if($(curChild).text().indexOf("failed") != -1){
              $(curChild).css({"background-color":"red !important"});
           } else {
              $(curChild).css({"background-color":"black !important"});
           }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: А когда вы вызываете функцию `highlightItems`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko когда загружается лист айтемов, то бишь в selectOneListbox
вызов выглядел примерно так `<script type="text/javascript">highlightSapItems();</script>`

Comment: В таком случае, приведите пример генерируемой `HTML` разметки на странице. Может быть у вас с селектором проблема.

Comment: Судя по всему, используется Primefaces. У них есть своё специфическое, но очень удобное решение этой задачи с помощью p:column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19405903/1341148 . Там немного неясно как работает комбинация f:selectItems и p:column, но разобраться можно...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что при установке стилей через атрибут `style` (`css` в jquery) нельзя, да и не нужно, использовать `!important`. Установленный стиль перебьет стиль в классе, если в классе он не объявлен `!important`.

```js
$('.without').css({
  'background-color': 'red!important'
});

$('.with').css({
  'background-color': 'red'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="without">without background</div>
<div class="with">with background</div>
```

Comment: Убрала `!important`, результата ноль. Пробую дебажить в браузере - просто скрипт не выполняется. Либо вызываю функцию не правильно, либо функция написана не правильно.

Comment: @DianaMeissen У вас может быть как минимум 3 ошибки: 1) Скрипт не вызывается\вызывается не вовремя. 2) Не верный селектор. 3) Стиль фона в классе у элемента стоит `!important`. Добавьте `console.log` в момент вызова, в условные блоки `if`.

Comment: думаю что всё же вызывается не вовремя. У меня основная страница и всплывающий диалог находятся в разных html файлах, скрипт отрабатывает когда загружается основная страница, а по идее должен лишь при появлении всплывающего диалога (хотя и находится в файле диалога). Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @DianaMeissen Для ответа на ваш вопрос надо лучше понимать структуру страниц и их взаимодействие. Приведите в вопросе примеры кода страниц.